# Migrating Data from a SQL Server Encrypted Table to SQL Azure using Azure Data Factory Copy data

Tags: sql-server, azure, encryption, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I am having difficulties with Azure Data Factory migrating data from an encrypted table. I was wondering what I have missed as I can't find a way to attach a certificate in the pipeline to extract the data.

I have a Link Service connection that connects successfully, but I am guessing it is possibly here that the certificate needs to be added for the decrypting on the data.

In 'Copy Data' the Source dataset, the Linked service connects to the database fine. But the Table, preview data Fails.

I get a 22301 error. The detail is as follows:

> A database operation failed with the following error:
> Failed to decrypt column ...
> Failed to decrypt a column encryption key using key store provider: 'MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE'. The last 10 bytes of the encrypted column encryption key are: '...'.
> Certificate with thumbprint '...' not found in certificate store 'My' in certificate location 'CurrentUser'. Verify the certificate path in the column master key definition in the database is correct, and the certificate has been imported correctly into the certificate location/store.
>
> Parameter name: masterKeyPath
>
> Failed to decrypt column ...
> Failed to decrypt a column encryption key using key store provider: 'MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE'. The last 10 bytes of the encrypted column encryption key are: '...'.
>
> Certificate with thumbprint '...' not found in certificate store 'My' in certificate location 'CurrentUser'. Verify the certificate path in the column master key definition in the database is correct, and the certificate has been imported correctly into the certificate location/store.
>
> Parameter name: masterKeyPath, SqlErrorNumber=0,Class=11,State=0,
>
> Certificate with thumbprint '...' not found in certificate store 'My' in certificate location 'CurrentUser'. Verify the certificate path in the column master key definition in the database is correct, and the certificate has been imported correctly into the certificate location/store.
>
> Parameter name: masterKeyPath
> Activity ID: ...

I have no idea what this means, is there someone who can explain what the problem is and how I can rectify this I would be extremely grateful.

What I am trying to achieve, with very little success is to migrate the data from the encrypted data table in one database unencrypted to another. I want to use an Azure Data factory pipeline and make redundant SSIS.

Many thanks

I have tried using the solution, however I am now getting this error.

Error **2200**.
**User configuration issue**

Failure happened on 'Source' side.

ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Failed to decrypt column 'Firstname'.

Failed to decrypt a column encryption key using key store provider: 'AZURE_KEY_VAULT'. Verify the properties of the column encryption key and its column master key in your database. The last 10 bytes of the encrypted column encryption key are: '##-##-##-##-##-##-##-##-##-##'.

Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.
Make sure "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider.Strings.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Failed to decrypt column 'Firstname'.

Failed to decrypt a column encryption key using key store provider: 'AZURE_KEY_VAULT'. Verify the properties of the column encryption key and its column master key in your database. The last 10 bytes of the encrypted column encryption key are: '##-##-##-##-##-##-##-##-##-##'.

Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.
Make sure "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider.Strings.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=0,Class=11,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=0,Errors=[{Class=11,Number=0,State=0,Message=Failed to decrypt column 'Firstname'.,},{Class=11,Number=0,State=0,Message=Failed to decrypt a column encryption key using key store provider: 'AZURE_KEY_VAULT'. Verify the properties of the column encryption key and its column master key in your database.

The last 10 bytes of the encrypted column encryption key are: 'AE-1D-E5-C1-60-F0-2F-42-3C-C1'.,},{Class=11,Number=0,State=0,Message=Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.

Make sure "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider.Strings.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.,},],''Type=System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException,Message=Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.

Make sure "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider.Strings.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.,Source=mscorlib,'

I'm really not sure what that all means, and from constant searching I have no solution to the problem. Why is this made so difficult, surely its just a handshake. It is very frustrating, I'm going to have to write a blog after I find the solution, I can't find anyone that has come across this issue before that wants to write about it.

Here is the setting up of ADF...
The Source SetUp
[image: Initial Setup]

Fails to read the table data, Fails with Error 22301

[image: Fails with Error 22301]

SSMS Keys for Encryption
[image: SSMS Encryption Keys]

Master Key
[image: Master Key]

Column Key
[image: Column Key]

Key in Azure Key Vault
[image: Azure Key Vault]

Link Service for Azure SQL Database
[image: Azure SQL Link service]

Link Service for SQL Server Database the encrypted data is here. It is supplied by a third party, i have no control over this.
[image: SQL Server Link Service]

The encrypted data is in the SQL Server Database, I want to decrypt this and save it to a table in my Azure SQL Database.

The columns are encrypted like so:
[Firstname] nvarchar COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [ColumnEncryptionKey], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Randomized, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL,

[image]

[image]

Comment: This https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCvOF.png has nothing to do with AlwaysEncrypted.  That's just fetching the SQL Auth password from Key Vault.  The Always Encrypted config is down lower.  And you need to make sure that it's configured properly for the SHIR that is actually connecting to your SQL Server.  IE if your SHIR isn't on an Azure VM then it can't have a "System Assigned Managed Identity".

Comment: @david-browne-microsoft. Excellent thank you. 
So can you help clear up what I need to do to get this to connect. 
The architecture is an encrypted SQL Server DB installed on an Azure VM, and I am trying to migrate this data to my SQL Database that is in a Resource Group with SQL Server using the Azure Data Factory. You've suggested what I can't do, but can you direct me to something I should do. How do I configure the Self-Host Integrated Runtime(SHIR)?

Comment: The SHIR will need to access the Always Encrypted key.  Docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server?tabs=data-factory#using-always-encrypted

Answer (score 0):

To transfer **Encrypted** data from data factory you have to use the `Azure key vault`:

- **Open the SQL Server Management Studio and connect with the server**.
- **Expand Database >> security >> Always Encrypted keys >> New Column master key.**

Give the master key a name, Choose the `Azure Key Vault` as your key storage location, login into your account, choose your `Azure subscription`, choose the `Azure key vault`, **generate the key**, and then click **"ok."**

[image]

- **Expand Database >> security >> Always Encrypted keys >> New Column Encryption key.**

Name your **column encryption key**, choose the **master key** and click on ok.

[image]

- **Encrypt columns**

To Encrypt a column or columns, **right-click on the Table**, click on **"Encrypt Columns**" and select single or multiple columns as per your requirement to encrypt.

- **Access policies**

To add an access policy, **open your Azure portal**, navigate to the `Azure key vault`, select the settings tab's `access policies` link, and then click `+ Add access policy`. `Select the principal`, **which is your Azure data factory name**, before choosing the important rights. Click on **Add** after selecting `Secret Permissions, followed by Certificate Permissions`.

[image]

- **linked service configuration**
  Create `linked service`, Name linked service, select `Azure subscription`, select the `server name`, select the `database name`, select the authentication type, provide the `user name and password`, select `always encrypted` select keystore authentication type as `System Assigned Managed Identity` and then click **ok create**.

[image]

**Create pipeline select source and sink and run the pipeline**

**Reference:** [Using Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database?tabs=data-factory#using-always-encrypted)

Comment: I have added my set up, I still am getting thrown an error.